# click(function() jquery Not working With Firefox but works perfect for other browsers :(

Tags: jquery, function, firefox, click

click(function() jquery Not working With Firefox but works perfect for other browsers :(     Why it doesn't works with Firefox Browser???

```js
/* phone number click to show */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Please what did I messed?

Comment: Please don't add text inside of your formatted code. Also, please try to ensure your code is properly indented when you post it. I've attempted to fix both issues. Please check to make sure it's correct.

Comment: Have you verified whether or not the `ready` function ever fires?